# How to add a dynamic javascript snippet to the footer that requires jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I know I can add a script file to the footer of theme that requires jquery with `wp_enqueue_script`, but i need to add dynamic javascript code to footer, somehing like this ...

```
if ( $body_logged_in == 'on' ) {
    $count = 60;            
} else {        
    $count = 90;        
}   
if ( $navbar_sticky == 'on' ) {

    $count = $count + 45;

}

?>

<script>

    $('.fixed-sidebar').stick_in_parent({offset_top: <?php echo $count; ?>});

</script>

<?php
```

I do this with `WP_footer` hook , is it safe and standard? or any better ways?

```
    function theme_wp_footer() {

    if ( $body_logged_in == 'on' ) {

        $count = 60;

    } else {

        $count = 90;    

    }

    if ( $navbar_sticky == 'on' ) {

        $count = $count + 45;

    }

    ?>

    <script>

        $('.fixed-sidebar').stick_in_parent({offset_top: <?php echo $count; ?>});

    </script>   
    <?php       
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'theme_wp_footer' );
```

How to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'is it safe' when placing scripts in the footer. The larger question is, have you tested your code to see if it works?

Comment: You've made it the best way possible, just one thing, wrap your code in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  /* your code */  });` to make it jQuery dependent, and make sure `jQuery` is enqueued (mostly done by your theme or a plugin, or else use `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obviously do it the way you did. However, there is a better way, that is much more maintainable than adding the script tag in the footer that way.

You can handle these sort of scenario (where you need dynamic variable from PHP) by using `wp_localize_script()` function.

For example, in `functions.php`:

```
function theme_wp_footer_scripts() {
    /* your custom CODE */
    if ( $body_logged_in == 'on' ) {
        $count = 60;
    } else {
        $count = 90;    
    }
    if ( $navbar_sticky == 'on' ) {
        $count = $count + 45;
    }

    /* add main script in footer */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'footer_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

    /* add dynamic data for your footer_script with object name footer_script_data */
    wp_localize_script( 'footer_script', 'footer_script_data',
        array( 
            'count' => $count
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_wp_footer_scripts' );
```

Then in `js/my-script.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    /* Your custom JavaScript CODE that is jQuery dependent */
    /* see how footer_script_data object name is used from external JavaScript file */
    $('.fixed-sidebar').stick_in_parent({offset_top: footer_script_data.count});    

});
```

Here's more about [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/).

Comment: There's a typo: `read` => `ready`